# Can find by return an arraycollection instead of array

Tags: symfony

I retrieve all objects for an entity like this:

```
$allQuestions = $em->getRepository('AppMyBundle:Question')
    ->findBy(array('isActive' => true, 'isDeleted' => false));
```

I get an array of objects into `$allQuestions`. Is there a possibility to get an `ArrayCollection` instead of an array?

Comment: You can convert it to an Arraycollection right ?

Comment: `ArrayCollection` it is an array of objects, you alredy getting the `ArrayCollection`, check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180651/arraycollection-in-symfony/29181036#29181036 response for more details about what it is an array collection

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could just do

```
$collection = new ArrayCollection($allQuestions);
```

To convert the array to an ArrayCollection.