# Use Doctrine ArrayCollection in symfony custom command

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I would like to use `ArrayCollection` in a custom symfony command.

But my way is throwing an error

> The class 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection' was not found in the chain configured namespaces AppBundle\Entity

My command

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\Gameworld;

class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('get:gw')
            ->setDescription('Populate gameworld')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

        $output->writeln('<info>Get current Gameworlds</info>');
        $gws = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Gameworld')->findAll();

        $gws = new ArrayCollection($gws);

        /* rest of the command */
    }
}
```

I tried to do `new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($gws);`

But the error is still there.

Hope you may help.

Comment: Add a stack trace to the question, please.

Comment: Have you looked at [Relationship Mapping Metadata](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#relationship-mapping-metadata)? Normally `ArrayCollection` is used in Entities for mapping. Your error says it's in the Entity file not the command file.

Comment: @Pete How can i give you that ?

Comment: @AlvinBunk `ArrayCollection` can also be used in controllers so maybe in custom commands too

Comment: `throw $gws = new ArrayCollection();` return `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Cannot throw objects that do not implement Throwable`

Comment: You don't understand what ArrayCollection is used for, also you can't pass a parameter to it when constructing a new object. Instead use `new ArrayCollection()`. Please [read this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180651/arraycollection-in-symfony) to understand how it is used. In that answer,@AlexandruOlaru give a good example of how to use it.

Comment: I can use array collections in my commands

Answer (score 1):

You probably tries to create instance of **ArrayCollection** in Gameworld constructor(or somewhere in related entities constructors), but you did not imported it with **use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;** call. Try to check your **AppBundle\Entity\Gameworld** class and its related entities for occurances of ArrayCollection and check whether you import it properly inside that classes.